# How do you change file association for .py Python files in XP?

Tags: python, windows, cmd, windows-xp, file-association

When I type `assoc .py` I get `.py=py_auto_file`.
When I type `ftype py_auto_file` I get `py_auto_file="C:\Program Files\Adobe\Photoshop 7.0\Photoshop.exe" "%1"`

How do I make `py_auto_file="C:\Python27"`?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It appears Photoshop may recognize a .py file format and has associated "py_auto_file" with the .py extension.

You can use the following command to locate the python file types:

```
C:\>ftype | findstr -i python
Python.CompiledFile="C:\Python27\python.exe" "%1" %*
Python.File="C:\Python27\python.exe" "%1" %*
Python.NoConFile="C:\Python27\pythonw.exe" "%1" %*
```

The next command shows the correct associations from my system:

```
C:\>assoc | findstr -i python
.py=Python.File
.pyc=Python.CompiledFile
.pyo=Python.CompiledFile
.pyw=Python.NoConFile
```

You can fix the associations with the following commands:

```
assoc .py=Python.File
assoc .pyc=Python.CompiledFile
assoc .pyo=Python.CompiledFile
assoc .pyw=Python.NoConFile
```

Comment: Thanks! After upgrading from Pyton 2.5 to 2.7 I found I have same issue and your fix helped.
Now I have dangling ftype-s "py_auto_file="D:\Python25\python.exe" "%1" %*" (same with pyc_auto_file) I'd like to remove. Do you know how to remove them?
(Tried ftype /h, of course :)

Comment: I think just setting them to blank: `ftype py_auto_file=`.  You can also delete them directly under `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT` in the registry via `regedit.exe`.

Comment: Under windows 10, this solution may not work if you have this key in your registry: `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications\python.exe` just delete this key, and it will work, otherwise you will need to modify the "command" entry to include the %* at the end of the command. [link](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-files/why-cant-i-change-the-default-program-from-command/e59d3d85-7161-4d3a-914e-9aeb3c72f6cb)

Answer (score 5):

You should pass script name `%1` and all command-line parameters `%*` to Python27 executable. To do this, simply execute

```
ftype py_auto_file="C:\Python27\bin\python.exe" "%1" %*
```

Comment: This didn't work for me but I found the py_auto_file entry in the registry and added %* to the end and that fixed my problems.

This was the error message I got when running the recommended ftype command:

File type 'py_auto_file' not found or no open command associated with it.

Comment: If you get `File type 'py_auto_file' not found or no open command associated with it.` or `File type 'PythonFile' not found or no open command associated with it.` then you should try by opening CMD as admin

Answer (score 0):

Right-click on .py file and set default program as python.exe

Comment: This doesn't pass command-line arguments along. If you do this then you need to edit the py_auto_file entry in the registry to add %* to the end of the command line.