# Getting "The syntax of the command is incorrect." when running new Amazon CLI

Tags: windows-7, python-2.7, amazon-web-services

Running Python27 on windows. Trying to run the new AWS command line interface (found here: http://aws.amazon.com/cli/)  , and getting the error "The syntax of the command is incorrect." when running anything.

Even "aws help" gives this error. I know everything is installed because a regular garbage command (asdf) gives a different error.

I get the same error in powershell as in cmd.

Googling around, the error is typically encountered when renaming/moving a file that has a space in it without using quote marks. I had hoped moving my python install to c:\python27\ would fix the issue, but it has not.

Comment: While not an answer to your question, if you are using windows, you could also user that AWS Tools for Windows PowerShell - https://aws.amazon.com/powershell/

Answer (score 0):

Moving python to a non-space having path was the correct choice.

The aws command is a little aggressive in finding all your python installs.  It searches your PATH directories for python.exe (or .bat or .cmd).  I had changed this manually when I moved my python directory.

It also searches your file associations (which I had not changed) and was still finding c:\program files\python27\ and was choking on the space.

This question helped me fix the file associations, and I'm good to go now.

[How do you change file association for .py Python files in XP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8196314/how-do-you-change-file-association-for-py-python-files-in-xp)

If you find the aws command slightly slow, you probably speed it up by skipping all this searching nonsense and just hard coding your python.exe path into the aws.cmd file.