# Python cannot find module even when path is appended to sys.path

Tags: python, python-2.7

Having some weird troubles installing python modules on my work computer (read: no admin/root rights), I'm using 2.7.5. I downloaded and unpacked the tarball and ran 'setup.py', but it had no effect: When I open the python shell, it can't find the module (this specific one is fuzzywuzzy). However, if I right click -> edit with IDLE the setup.py, and then run the shell from that file, it loads and works perfectly fine. Or, if I then open a new file from that shell, use the module and run it, it works fine. -__-

I've tried using:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('path here')
```

to append the location where the module is installed, but this doesn't help, nor does the path stay in the sys.path list when I close/reopen the shell.

This is actually driving me insane. Can anyone help? I'm relatively new to programming and python.

Comment: Are you sure you're running `setup.py` with the same interpreter you're trying to `import` into?

Comment: Are you using windows or mac? If windows add path manually in `Environmental Variables`

Comment: Do you have more than one version of Python installed? Calling `setup.py` *can* use a different Python to calling `python setup.py`.

Comment: See this possibly related question about [Python file associations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8196314/how-do-you-change-file-association-for-py-python-files-in-xp).

Comment: you should add the path to the PYTHONPATH environment variable. To see which paths python actually knows about, open a command shell and execute `python -m site`

Answer (score 1):

The best and easy way provided by python to install/uninstall packages is to use PIP.
use this

```
python -m pip install packagename==version
```

same way to uninstall

```
python -m pip uninstall packagename==version
```

if you are using windows you need to set path variable first usually python file will be in path C:\Python27 to set path variable

```
PATH=%PATH%;C:\Python27;
```